# how to check the charfield choice instance

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, django-rest-framework

i need to check the charfield choice instance, representing a role for permissions, however i cannot obtain that

here's models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('ADMIN', 'admin'),
        ('USER', 'user'),
        ('MODERATOR', 'moderator'),
        )
    role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=ROLE_CHOICES[1], max_length=500)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['role']
```

view permission func:

```
    def get_permissions(self):
        print(self.request.user.role)
        print(self.request.user.role)
        print(self.request.user.role)
        print(self.request.user.role)
        print('vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvk')
        if self.request.user.role == 'user':
            print(self.request.user.role)
        if self.request.user.role == 'USER':
            print(self.request.user.role)
        if self.request.user.role == ('USER', 'user'):
            print(self.request.user.role)
        if self.request.user.role in ['USER', 'user']:
            print(self.request.user.role)
            print('aaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
        if self.action == 'create' or self.action == 'perform_create':
            permission_classes = []
        elif self.action == 'list' or self.action == 'retrieve':
            permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
        # elif self.action == 'list':
        #     permission_classes = [IsAboveUser]
        elif self.action == 'destroy' or self.action == 'update' or self.action == 'partial_update':
            permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
        else:
            permission_classes = [IsAdmin]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

out:

```
('USER', 'user')
('USER', 'user')
('USER', 'user')
('USER', 'user')
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvk
```

so noting passes the check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `default=ROLE_CHOICES[1]` should be `default=ROLE_CHOICES[1][0]` to not give the tuple as default, but the value `'user'`.

Also have a look at the new [enumeration types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) available since Django 3.1 that make these kinds of mistakes much harder to make.